# Finding initial values for linear systems of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution of the system
>   $$\begin{cases} x_1'= -x_1+3x_2-3x_3 \\ x_2'=-2x_1+x_2 \\ x_3'=-2x_1+3x_2-2x_3\end{cases}$$
>   and the set of initial values such that the solution tends to $0$ when $t\to \infty$ (similarly for the case $t\to -\infty$).

I'm not exactly sure if I'm interpreting this exercise correctly. Given the coefficient matrix,

$$A= \pmatrix{-1 & 3 & -3 \\ -2 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 3 & -2}$$

I computed $A$'s Eigenvalues ($1,-1,-2$) and Eigenvectors ($(0,1,1),(1,1,1), (3/2,1,3/2)$ respectively). The general solution of the homogeneous system can then be expressed as

$$X(t)=c_1e^t \pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ 1} + c_2e^{-t} \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 1} + c_3e^{-2t} \pmatrix{3/2 \\ 1 \\ 3/2}$$

But this is a vector-valued function, right? So its limit should a vector.

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} X(t) = c_1 \lim_{t\to \infty} e^t \pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ 1} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0} \iff c_1=0 \\ \lim_{t\to -\infty} X(t) = c_2 \lim_{t\to \infty} e^{-t} \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 1} + c_3 \lim_{t \to -\infty}e^{-2t} \pmatrix{3/2 \\ 1 \\ 3/2} =\pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0} \iff c_2=c_3=0$$

So... the initial value should be $X(0)= \pmatrix{3/2 c_3 \\ c_2 + c_3 \\ c_2 + 3/2 c_3}$ in the first case and $X(0)= \pmatrix{c_1 \\ c_1 \\ c_1}$ in the second case?

Comment: You need $c_1 = 0$. Also, it looks like you swapped eigenvectors for two eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for $$X(t)=c_1e^t \pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ 1} + c_2e^{-t} \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 1} + c_3e^{-2t} \pmatrix{3/2 \\ 1 \\ 3/2}$$

to approach $0$ you have to have $c_1 =0$ so your solution is $$X(t)= c_2e^{-t} \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 1} + c_3e^{-2t} \pmatrix{3/2 \\ 1 \\ 3/2}$$

which tends to zero for all values of $c_1$ and $c_2$